# Network not working after Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

I recently installed Windows 10 on my Lenovo G500 laptop, but after that i found that none of the wireless network and the local area connection is working.
Any suggestions where i can start ?

Comment: For whatever reason, the upgrade does not always seem to update or reinstall the current drivers. I've heard of many people having problems with multiple drivers. The drivers appear in device manager and look like they are installed, but do not work. After removing and reinstalling the drivers, everything works like normal.

Comment: If you have a 3rd party firewall, like bitdefender say, then this can be a problem.  Also some VPN clients are known to cause issues on upgrade such as Cisco AnyConnect.  Please think of what else you may have installed that would interfere with networking, i.e. Security, VPN, Networking Apps and Visualization Products.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the drivers are not installed by default. Go to the Lenovo website and download the drivers for your LAN and Wifi.

Answer (score 0):

If Lenovo doesn't have Windows 10 supporting drivers, head over to whomever created your internal wifi and nic and look for compatible drivers there.

Answer (score 0):

If Internet not working after upgrading window's just go to Run  type Type “netsh winsock reset” your problem will get resolve