# Local UNC paths through virtual switch failed after Windows 10 Pro update to 1511

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-10-v1511

After allowing a Windows 10 Pro system to use Windows Update to apply the 1511 version upgrade (build 10586.3), my Hyper-V Virtual Switch failed with an error reporting "Static MAC address 'B8-CA-3A-7F-97-F8' for 'vEthernet (New Virtual Switch)' (017CBB32-2B9B-49F7-B257-3614649BAF21) conflicts with another adapter." although the error I saw was less specific. (The message here is from the Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V-VMMS\Networking event log in Event Viewer > Applications and Services Logs.)

I dropped the existing switch and created a new one.

That gave me Internet (and local TCP) access, but local UNC paths and related infrastructure fails. (UNC paths and mapped drives for a VPN now worked.)

What should I try next?

<sub>There are related questions, but most are referring to total networking loss.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:  `netsh winsock reset` and a reboot fixes this.

(It happened again for the 28/11/15 KB3120677 Cumulative Update.)

---

I tried the "Shared Folders" troubleshooter and it explained "Windows Sockets registry entries required for network connectivity are missing".

I found a similar issue on Microsoft Technet suggesting `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` which I've tried and rebooted after.

This stopped the troubleshooter finding any problems, but my issue itself remained.

I then issued `netsh winsock reset`, because of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/959212/39835) and rebooted again, and that fixed it.